# Parse local data store crashing my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm using Parse local data store, I set it up like this:

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];

[Parse setApplicationId:@"MY ID "
              clientKey:@"MY CLIENT KEY"];
```

I'm using my real client key and ID,  after a few moments my app crashes and this is the log I get in the Xcode console.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'BFMultipleExceptionsException', reason: 'There were multiple exceptions.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1856fa59c 0x195e500e4 0x1002f5acc 0x10030ad80 0x100281030 0x1006e4e30 0x1006e4df0 0x1006f19a0 0x1006f2f18 0x1966712e4 0x196670fa8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

any idea on what is happening?

Comment: How do you know it is due to the Parse local data store? Can you provide more information on the exception that is thrown?

Comment: I set an `All Objective-C Exceptions` that is firing on methods that is connected to the parse local data store, however that is all information I have about the crash, that is all that is being thrown.

Comment: Where do you setApplicationId:clientKey: is it on application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ??

Comment: @MihribanMinaz Yes, however this issue was already fixed in a new sdk version